# What's the difference between these ways of calling the superclass's constructor?

Tags: python, inheritance

What if anything is the important difference between the following uses of calling the superclass initiation function?

```
class Child_1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

class Child_2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent, self).__init__()

class Child_3(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
```

Comment: those aren't meta classes

Comment: That's not what inheritance covers.

Comment: what should I call the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first form (though you'd fix the typo and make it Child_1 in the call to super) would be what you'd generally want. This will look up the correct method in the inheritence hierarchy.

For the second form, you're looking for parents classes of Parent that implement this method, and you'd have to have a very special use case (if you want to skip a parent, don't derive from them) in order to want to do that.

The third in many cases would wind up doing the same as the first, though without seeing the code for Parent, it's hard to be sure. The advantage of the first method over the third is that you can change the base class of the child and the right method will still be called.

Also, the first form allows for cooperative multiple inheritence. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351508/pythons-super-function) or [this writeup](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#cooperation) to understand the cases where this would be useful or necessary.